# What does YCWCYODFTRFDTY mean?

Tags: australia, languages, northern-territory

In several outback pubs in central Australia, including [Cadney Homestead](https://retail.mogasregional.com.au/pages/site_location_details.aspx?listing_type=0&site_id=zWrCQJtZ69HrjlET8WLUiNvU0RdW3jwJ%2F83bmbRqEk8%3D) (below) and [Stuarts Well Roadhouse](https://www.stuartswellroadhouse.com.au/), there's a prominent sign at the bar with the cryptic message "YCWCYODFTRFDTY":

[image]

**What does this mean?**

And I'll save you the trouble: at time of asking, [Google doesn't know](https://www.google.com/search?q=ycwcyodftrfdty)!  (In the text results, at least, you may find the answer if you scrutinize the images well enough.)  But if you do, please use [spoiler markup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/72878/178422) (start line with `>!`) in your answer.

**Update**: This is, inevitably, now Google's top hit for the phrase. Some lazy bum ripped it off to Quora, and there's a [creative answer](https://qr.ae/TWI2gv) there as well!

Comment: Now Google does know; it returns this as the first result

Comment: So now pay up!!

Comment: Did you ask there?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Actually, various sources on Google told me

> "Your curiosity will cost you one dollar for the Royal Flying Doctor thank you"
> .
>
>  The [Royal Flying Doctor Service](https://www.flyingdoctor.org.au) provides routine and emergency medical services to remote rural communities throughout Australia.

[Here's one source](http://www.caravanersforum.com/viewtopic.php?t=57749&start=10300), scroll down a little way.

Edit:

> it was my understanding that the RFDS was entirely funded by donations but it seems this is not the case. I've removed that reference from my answer, but don't let that stop you donating!

Comment: You might want to explain, for those who aren't aware, what the "RFD" is.

Comment: After traveling in outback Australia, wholeheartedly donate. Everyone out there seems to know someone who is alive or able-bodied because of the Royal Flying Doctor service, and it runs on donations. So by all means, ask when you see the sign, and happily part with a dollar.

Comment: Maybe you can put a link to a site where they tell you how to donate (from abroad as well?) for those of us who do not see those buckets.

Comment: @willeke I've already included a link to the RFDS web site, but details on how to donate can be found [here](https://www.flyingdoctor.org.au/support-us/)

Comment: I missed it, it is under 'Donate Now to SA/NT', and it does mention 'country if not Australia'.

Comment: @Jason While the RFDS does good work, their yearly budget is $340m and they're mostly funded by taxpayers, not donations.

Comment: Tried to donate $1. Minimum donation is $2...

Comment: @Masclins You're way too curious, so it's two bucks for you!

Comment: I've seen things like this in the US as well, usually in the form of "YCJCY..." meaning "Your Curiosity Just Cost You..." and the rest varies depending on how much they feel you should donate and to whom.

Comment: Another US form is "IITYWIM..." which stands for "If I Tell You What It Means..." and is often followed by things like Will You Buy Me A Shot or A Beer.

Comment: @Masclins just checking - the minimum *tax deductable* donation for charities in Australia is $2 - could that be what you were thinking of?

Comment: Thanks for the link to my "creative answer" on Quora. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

> Your curiosity will cost you a three dollar donation for the Royal Flying Doctors Thank you.

Comment: That doesn't match the acronym, does it?

Comment: @Berend It matches the recent inflation rate in Australia though.

Comment: @Berend they probably updated the sign to YCWCYTDFTRFDTY or something similar.

Comment: @jcaron possible, but that's not in the question